# How unique are local asset URLS in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, core-foundation

We are using local asset URLs to identify images coming from Camera Roll of an iPhone. 
These are ALAssetPropertyURLs described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html

We know that the URLs are persisted across backup/restore. We would like to use the ids to uniquely identify images (so when we backup and restore the same images between two devices, we would like to know - cheaply - that these are actually the same images).

The question is: how unique are those local URLs? Are they unique per device (seems so) or maybe we can assume they are unique across devices (I guess this is hard to achieve, so probably it is not done this way). Apple's documentation and source code is not clear on the subject.

One of our ideas is to use also asset's timestamp (it also persists across backup restore) and build asset_unique_id = asset_id + timestamp.

Any better ideas? We would like to avoid checking the content of the image and calculating hashes, because it's pretty intensive computationally and if the above (or similar) approach works, it would be much better.

Comment: If I am getting you correctly, you want to compare to assets using their asset url ?? if they are same or not ?? asset url from one device and the asset from another ??

Comment: @JarekPotiuk any resolution to this?  Would really like to know what is persisted across backups/restores.  The asseturl/ids?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in this, from my testing I have found the URL to be unique to each device. In fact, I checked the same image in three different scenarios and got a different result for each:

Original image on iPhone: ID = 484299F8-C176-4ED3-B944-B7E6F7BE59CE

From second device(iPad) through Photostream: ID = 5092A342-5B7D-496D-BC1C-C9FC0BAB2D91

Saved to iPad from photostream: ID = F7D225EE-30A2-4415-A1DC-85550350ECEB

I too was hoping to use this ID across devices to know if they were the same image. If you have found another solution I would love to know.